# How to use an S4 Object using VB RdotNet?

Tags: r, vb.net, arules, r.net, market-basket-analysis

I am using R.DOTNET nuget package in vb.NET.
I developed R project using **arules** package. I save the workspace as RDATA file.

i can access the RDATA file and easily access the variables. 
But in package there are some S4 object like **rules** for Basket Analysis.

But i cannot see .AsS4 variables in rdotnet.

```
    engine.Evaluate("load('Allin.RData')")
    Dim foo = engine.Evaluate("foo").AsCharacter() ' No problem
    Dim Arule = engine.Evaluate("rule").AsS4() ''Problem No AsS4 Extension
```

In question  [34355201](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355201/how-to-create-an-s4-object-using-rdotnet) i see AsS4 extension in C# project
but i cannot see it in VB. 
[This is image shows the situation](http://oi66.tinypic.com/vifjw8.jpg)
Thanks.